# How to save the prawn pdf on rails root without rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, save, prawn

Here my code rendering pdf is ok .But I don't want render directly save to the rails folder how?

Help me please

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html   # show.html.erb
  format.xml    { render :xml => @claim }
  format.report { render_report }
  format.xls    { render_report }
  format.pdf    { render :layout => false }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood well... if you want to have downloadable pdf, you could do something like this:

```
format.pdf {send_data your_pdf, :type => 'application/pdf'}
```

You didn't say which version of rails are you using, but in general methods [send_data](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#M000224) and [send_file](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#M000223) could be usefull for you (links are to v 2.3.8, but of course those methods exist in newer versions).

Comment: format.pdf { send_data "#{@claim.id}".pdf, :type => 'application/pdf' }

Comment: your_pdf in send_data should be a binary data, if you have path_to_your_file, you should do format.pdf {send_file path_to_your_file, :type => 'application/pdf'}

Comment: in your case: format.pdf { send_file "#{@claim.id}.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf' } - '.pdf' should be inside quotation

Comment: sorry an error showing again "cannot read file" . Actually i  mean  saving pdf not to download

Comment: hmmm - so I guess this is what you need ;) Render file somewhere before final respond_to: http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Document.html#method-i-render_file

Comment: Thanks i want to know one information that, is it possible to save prawn pdf automatically to server ?